# Why Chrome close without close() or quit()?

Tags: python, selenium

My ChromeDriver version is 2.22

In my code, there is no quit() or close(), but Chrome browser closes after execution every time.

But if I change webdriver to Firefox, it works well.

My code is

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time

def scrapy_list_from_youtube_list(url):
    browser = webdriver.Chrome()
    browser.get(url)

    links = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('pl-video-title-link')
    download_list = []
    for link in links:
        download_list.append(link.get_attribute('href'))
        print download_list
    i = 0
    for download_link in download_list[0:2]:
        try:
            browser.get('http://www.en.savefrom.net/')
            inout = browser.find_element_by_id('sf_url')
            inout.send_keys(download_link)
            inout.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
            time.sleep(20)
            c = browser.find_element_by_link_text('Download')
            print i
            # print c.get_attribute('href')
            c.click()

            i = i +1
        except Exception as e:
            print e



scrapy_list_from_youtube_list('https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLqjtD4kfVG7OFk0vLP1BxUJTmN3-Uj9qM')
```

Comment: did you get an exception message ?

Comment: No exception message

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. But my code had the line `driver.close()` in it. I removed that line and my chrome window didn't close after completion of execution. Try to get a similar workaround.